# Looking to limit post size on a category "page"

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm looking to display the excerpt of posts in a Category being pulled into a custom page template.

As it sits now all category post pulled into the page are showing the entire post.  I'd like to show roughly 40 words (or x number of characters) followed by "read more>>" excerpt.

Additionally I'd like to max out the number of posts displayed on the page to roughly 5 more or less.

```
 <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
 <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>   

 <?php
 $catPost = get_posts('cat=225&posts_per_page=3');
 foreach ($catPost as $post) : setup_postdata($post); 
 ?>

 <?php get_template_part('content'); ?>
 <?php endforeach;?>
 <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>
 <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

Comment: Great that you want to do that! And why are you here?

Comment: You should consider talking about what you have tried.  SO does not provide all of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `the_content()` in content template by the following code

```
   $content = get_the_content();
   $trimmed_content = wp_trim_words( $content, 40, '<a href="'. get_permalink() .'"> ...' . Read More . '</a>' );
   echo trimmed_content;
```

Or you can use the following code to your `functions.php` file

```
   function excerpt($num) {
    $limit = $num+1;
    $excerpt = explode(' ', get_the_excerpt(), $limit);
    array_pop($excerpt);
    $excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt)." <a href='" .get_permalink($post->ID) ." ' class='".readmore."'>Read More</a>";
    echo $excerpt;
  }

function excerpt_length($length) {
  return 40;
}
add_filter('excerpt_length', 'excerpt_length');
```

Now replace `the_content()` by `the_excerpt()` in content template.

Comment: Thank you Bir - Your second suggestion is the ticket.  Thank you kindly!

Answer (score 0):

add this to your function.php file

```
function new_excerpt_length($length) {
    return 40;
}
add_filter('excerpt_length', 'new_excerpt_length');
```

where that 40 is the number of characters you want to display